# Why do people say "It was a busy four days"?

Tags: grammaticality

> It was a busy four days

Is the sentence correct? Why "it", and why "a busy"?

Comment: It is correct. It means, *I/We have been busy for the last four days* (possibly *very busy*). Closer to the original perhaps is *The past four days have been very busy for me/us.* Why something occurs in an English idiom is often impossible to answer.

Comment: The 'a' in the sentence groups the four days as a period of time.  Also "It's been a _busy week/month/year_" etc.

Comment: 'It' refers to the (four-day) period that has been mentioned previously in such conversations (an example of which you should have included). 'Busy' is a transferred epithet, like 'proud' in 'It was a proud day for John's parents' and 'quiet' in 'She had a quiet pint at the local'.

Comment: "It (=the time period) was a busy (set of) 4 days." They're describing a period of time. It was 4 days. They're telling you they were very busy during that time, to the extent that the days themselves could be thought of as busy - not just the individual days, but the entire period of time they are talking about.

Comment: Consider ***It was a long movie***, which involves applying the same kind of "inversion" and "existential 'it'" to ***The movie was long***. What that shows is we switch from *definite* article in standard S-V-O constructions to *indefinite* article in the inverted form (in OP's case we'd use the definite article for the underlying "standard" utterance ***The four days were busy***).

Comment: @Elijah: I think if you want to say ***it*** refers to anything in particular, it refers to ***four days***. What kind of "four days"? - A ***busy*** four days.

Answer (score 1):

Whereas many other languages such as French tend to be rather formalist, there is a general tendency in English to treat phrases as if they had the grammatical features they 'should have' (in the current context, based on meaning) rather than those they actually have on a superficial level. This is particularly true for singular vs. plural, and it is why people say things such as "Whitehall *are* divided on the matter" or "The Beatles *was* a British band". The details of how this is handled in corner cases vary between the variants of English (notably between American and British English), but the basics are the same everywhere. (It also works for other grammatical features. E.g. a company named "Silly Girl" would be referred to as *it*, not as *she*. French and German are examples of the numerous languages that work differently in this respect.)

In this case, the four days are treated as a singular because it is conceived of as a single period rather than a sequence of individual days. That alone would probably not be sufficient reason, but the phrase in question is just a variant of what is often heard with established periods of time that are singulars even grammatically:

- It was a busy year.
- It was a busy month.
- It was a busy fortnight.
- It was a busy week.
- It was a busy weekend.
- ... four days.

It's clear that there should be some valid way of completing the last sentence. One way of doing so is by treating the phrase "four days" as a singular. Initially, people were probably quite reluctant about doing so - but what is the alternative?

If we want to be 100% formally correct and pedantic in a way that not even French is, we need to say this:

- They were four busy days.

However, in this kind of context English always uses "It is" instead of "They are", even in connection with plurals. After this correction we get the following:

- It was four busy days.

But maybe this is not really what we mean. We are not talking about Monday, Wednesday, Thursday and Saturday being busy, and we are also not talking about each of Monday to Thursday individually being a busy day. It was a single, uninterrupted busy period lasting four days. I.e., it wasn't "four busy days", but rather "busy four days".

- It was busy four days.

But this is actually ungrammatical. So much so, that outside the present context one wouldn't even be able to tell with some certainty what this is supposed to mean. ("It was busy four days later"?) If we already treat the four-day period as a single entity, then just like we say "It was a busy week" rather than "It was busy week", we also have to supply the indefinite article in this case:

- It was a busy four days.